facing problems running angular server
\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\util\reportUnhandledError.js:13
throw err;
^
Error: The service was stopped: write EPIPE
at C:\Sistema\ProntMed\Front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:993:26
at responseCallbacks. (C:\Sistema\ProntMed\Front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
at afterClose (C:\Sistema\ProntMed\Front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:613:28)
at C:\Sistema\ProntMed\Front\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1984:18
at onwriteError (node:internal/streams/writable:603:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
Node.js v22.6.0
I already tried to download esbuild, I deleted node_modules and package.lock.json but when I tried to install them again it showed me the error above, I tried to install the dependencies but the error continued, I deleted all files related to node and angular and I restarted the project but the error persists. When I try on another PC, the server runs
